# Angular router not finding child route

Tags: angular

I am having a problem with my nested router outlet. In my Angular project I have defined the following routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DefaultLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: LandingPageComponent, outlet: 'default' },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: DefaultLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: LoginRegisterComponent, outlet: 'default' },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    component: DefaultLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: LoginRegisterComponent, outlet: 'default' },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'companies',
    component: CmsLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: CompanyIndexComponent, outlet: 'cms' },
      { path: ':id', component: CompanyViewComponent, outlet: 'cms' },
    ]
  },
];
```

Now I don't think I did this the most efficient way but I wasn't sure how to define this correctly, but what you see is that I have 2 different page layouts. When I navigate to '', 'login' and 'register', I want to use the `DefaultLayoutComponent`, which contains:

```
<router-outlet name="default"></router-outlet>
```

And when I navigate to the 'companies' page, I want the `CmsLayoutComponent`. Now this works when I go to: http://localhost:4200/companies.

However, on that page I show a few companies and when I click on one of them I want to navigate to: http://localhost:4200/companies/1 for example. To do that, I have this method:

```
viewCompany(companyId: number) {
  this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { cms: ['companies', companyId] } }]);
}
```

But when running this, I get this error:

```
core.mjs:8416 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'companies/2'
Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'companies/2'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.mjs:3654:16)
```

I also get this error when I try to navigate to:

```
viewCompany(companyId: number) {
  this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { cms: ['companies'] } }]);
}
```

which should be the same page as I already was on, but this returns in the same error but then for the /companies path.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the `:id` is read as optional by angular.

Try this:

```js
{
  path: 'companies',
  component: CmsLayoutComponent,
  children: [
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: CompanyIndexComponent, outlet: 'cms' },
    { path: ':id', component: CompanyViewComponent, outlet: 'cms' },
  ]
}
```

In your case, adding the `pathMatch: 'full'` will ensure that you will go to `CompanyIndexComponent` only if you don't have an ID provided in your URL.

More info in the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/Route#pathMatch).

Comment: It can still not find the http://localhost:4200/companies/1 page, but it does find it when I put it outside the children in the root defined as: `companies/:id`

Comment: Can you try inverting the children lines ? `':id'` in first and `''` in last ?